# Is it possible to run an infinite loop and not blocking the flow of execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a bot using discord.js and I want to change the presence every 5 minutes to a random one, I have some presences stored in another file like this:

presences.js:

```
module.exports = {
  p1: ['LISTENING', 'music'],
  p2: ['WATCHING', 'a movie'],
  p3: ['PLAYING', 'a game']
};
```

And in the main file I get them and choose a random one using randomPresence(presences)

```
const presences = require("./presences");

 var randomPresence = function(obj) {
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
   return obj[keys[(keys.length * Math.random()) << 0]];
 };
```

How would I make it so every 5 minutes it chooses a random presence using the function above and sets it?

Comment: Check out [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` function for add timeout and [`client.user.setPresence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) for set activity type and name.

```js
module.exports = {
    activity: [
        {
            type: 'LISTENING',
            text: 'music',
        },
        {
            type: 'WATCHING',
            text: 'a movie',
        },
        {
            type: 'PLAYING',
            text: 'a game',
        },
    ],
};
```

```js
const presences = require('./presences');
// dont forgot to export and import client if it not declarated
setInterval(() => {
    let randomType = presences[Math.floor(Math.random() * presences.length)];
    client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: randomType.name }, type: randomType.type });
}, 300000);
```